# Create a generic stack implemented with a linked-list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, linked-list, function-pointers

I want to create a generic stack. I want to implement it with a linked-list.

I created this structures **stack_l** :

```
typedef struct stack
 {
   void * data;

   void (*copy)(void *o);

   struct stack *next;

 } stack_l;
```

I have some questions:

---

- The second field of the structures is a pointer to a function, to copy a new data (passing by argument in a function Push).
  The prototype of the function Push is:

> stack_l * Push( stack_l * head, void * d );

1. Is it correct how I pass the pointer to the function copy?
2. I have to implement it in the function Push??

---

- Is it necessary create a function NewStack (for example) to inizialize the field of the structures, or is better have only a Push function that create the 1st element if the stack is empty, and add new element on top if there is at least one element?

---

- A ***void **** need to be allocated with a malloc ?

Comment: Obviously I created also a Pop function to remove elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not require different identifiers for `stack` and `stack_l`. Now, to your questions:

Your `Push` function is incompatible with the type of the `copy` field in `stack_l`. If you want to include a pointer to (member-)functions in your `struct` to make it look like C++, you still have to pass your object to these functions.

Yes ,you have to implement your functionality somewhere, and that cannot be within the definition of `struct stack`. This means that you do need some sort of constructor function (you may call it `newStack` if you like). Your constructor must at least initialise your function pointers (if you want to keep them). If you opt not to keep these function pointers you can put the initialisation code well in your `push` routine, as you suggested:

```
stack_l* stackPush(stack_l* head, void* content) {
  // head might be NULL, meaning the stack is "empty" or it might be an actual pointer
  // we don't care
  stack_l* const front = malloc(sizeof(stack_l));
  *front = (stack_l){.data = content, .next = head};
  return front;
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly state what the empty stack is. So you may want to implement a constructor for clarity:

```
stack_l* stackCreateEmpty() {
  retun NULL;
}
```

And maybe even a destructor:

```
void stackDestroyEmpty(stack_l* s) {
  assert(s == NULL && "Tried to destroy non-empty stack.");
}
```

To your last question: As you see above, you have to use `malloc` to get space to hold your `stack_l` object, other than that, you do not need to allocate extra space for your `void*` member, as it is part of `stack_l`.

Comment: Thanks for comment.

I just don't understand if is necessary my function copy if you assign  the void* content to data with .data = content.

Probably I don't undestand well.

Comment: @Kyrol: You don't have to! As I said, it is just for clarity, so the user of your stack implementation has some interface to hold on to. Regarding `copy`: Since your stack only stores `void` pointers (it stores the literal value of the pointer, not the stuff it points to), you do not have to implement a copy function, you simply verbatim-copy the pointer. **However**, if you **do** want to to copy what the pointer points to, you have to provide a custom copy parameter to the push function, because your stack can impossibly know what you're storing in it. Hope this helps you, otherwise ask.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding about constructor!

About `copy`: ok, If I write the function with the maximum of generic property, I don't need that function. But if I call Push in a main, and I want to store in data an int (for example), I need that function, isn't it?

Comment: another thing: why you declare front as `const` ??

Comment: @Kyrol: To put it differently, if your `stack` owns the data, you have to provide some means of copying your data (i.e. something that knows the semantics and size of what the `void*` argument points to). However, if you want your stack to simply keep track of the pointer itself, you do not require a copy mechanism.  Regarding `front`, I did not plan to change the pointer, and I have the habit, to make everything as unmutable and as local as possible (maybe some residual fetish from functional programming). It often prevents mistakes!